# How to use Xpath match assertion in soapUI

Tags: xpath, soapui

Here is the response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getContactResponse xmlns:ns="http://uta.WS.abc.com">
         <ns:return><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><ssdoc><WSResponse>
<Code></Code>
<FieldName></FieldName>
<FieldValue></FieldValue>
<Description></Description>
</WSResponse><contact><ssid>1222885</ssid><fields><field><id>userid</id><name>userid</name><value>1222885</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>Companyid</id><name>Companyid</name><value>493500</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>_companyname</id><name>_companyname</name><value>QA</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>Firstname</id><name>Firstname</name><value>Web Services</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>lastname</id><name>lastname</name><value>User</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>title</id><name>title</name><value>dr</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>email</id><name>email</name><value>webservices@abc.com</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>phone</id><name>phone</name><value>416 591 1668</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>uaddress</id><name>uaddress</name><value>111 Peter Street</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>ucity</id><name>ucity</name><value>Toronto</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>ustate</id><name>ustate</name><value>Ontario</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>ucountryid</id><name>ucountryid</name><value>10</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>upostalcode</id><name>upostalcode</name><value>M5V2H1</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>_lastmodified</id><name>_lastmodified</name><value>2015-11-26 14:58:39</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>isexternal</id><name>isexternal</name><value>0</value><fieldtype>1</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2866410</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2866410'>UserId</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2727681</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727681'>SYS ADMIN ONLY</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2727682</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727682'>ARCADIA X ONLY</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2727946</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727946'>Web Services Field QA</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2732328</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2732328'>QA CF Shown when New</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2732329</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2732329'>QA CF hiden when New</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2728787</id><name><![CDATA[<span class='Required' title='Required'>* </span><label for='cf_2728787'>Date field</label><fieldinstruction><div class="FormInstructions">please enter DOB</div></fieldinstruction>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858611</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858611'>Password Restriction</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697866</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697866'>ComboBox for Subreport Testing long tool tip message field</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value>1</value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2727819</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727819'>UTA TEST ROLE ONLY</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2780610</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2780610'>MULTI ADDRES RO FIELD</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2804779</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2804779'>#$%^&*(()</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697254</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697254'>UTA Test Role 1-base field</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697324</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697324'>~Applicant number</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2698432</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2698432'>Test for ROSV - Base Role</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2708967</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2708967'>RO Test field</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2727787</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727787'>Arcadia X Field</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697845</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697845'>Field populated by workflow</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value>2013-10-23 15:49</value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2858720</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858720'>Date of Hire</label><fieldinstruction><div class="FormInstructions">When did employee started working?</div></fieldinstruction>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2698442</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2698442'>Test for ROSV2 - Base Role</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2858721</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858721'>Shift Rotation</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858686</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2858686'>Hourly Salary</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858687</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2858687'>Annual Salary</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2727701</id><name><![CDATA[<span class='Required' title='Required'>* </span><label for='cf_2727701'>mandatoryfield</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2727788</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727788'>Applicant Field Caching</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697837</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697837'>~Search 1</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value>r</value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2805087</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2805087'>Roles assigned</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2708968</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2708968'>Roles with Brackets test</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2827085</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2827085'>hidden from sys admin</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2832191</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2832191'>ORCID</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2698276</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2698276'>Contact currency</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2712363</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2712363'>Dynamic control sub-field A</label><fieldinstruction><div class="FormInstructions">instruction text no italics</div></fieldinstruction>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2712364</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2712364'>Dynamic control sub-field B</label><fieldinstruction><div class="FormInstructions">instruction text no italics</div></fieldinstruction>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697502</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697502'>Comp Match User Field</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697327</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697327'>registrant field-user</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697343</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697343'>Show Header</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697855</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697855'>--</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697856</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697856'>--</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2832310</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_v2832310'>Association 1</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>111</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2697405</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697405'>userrole-text</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697411</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697411'>userrole-sec1-System Admin can not edit</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2728498</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2728498'>~Multiline </label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>40</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2732333</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2732333'>Assistant Email</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2748473</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2748473'>Combo Box in Advanced Search</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2734113</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2734113'>Checkbox options</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2734115</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2734115'>Exposed if a</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2734116</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2734116'>Field only for EF</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2734404</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2734404'>ro delete </label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2729087</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2729087'>Field populated by User Status workflow</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2728899</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2728899'>QA Sys Variable field </label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2697848</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697848'>Field holding users timezone</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2727707</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727707'>Field Holding Users Local Time </label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2697850</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_v2697850'>Field holding association details</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>111</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2739256</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2739256'>Field Holding Users Language</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2710361</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2710361'>ATS list view RP</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2710362</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2710362'>ATS list view JS</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2727789</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727789'>Field Caching</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2698345</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2698345'>Roles ids</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2727791</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727791'>List of Sub Orgs</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2727793</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2727793'>Advanced Search field </label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2697835</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697835'>Workflow Field</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2827355</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2827355'>Stored Country ID</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2697584</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697584'>Stored Address</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2697567</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697567'>~Contact Single File</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>33</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2697568</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697568'>~Contact Multi File</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>80</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2697569</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2697569'>A contact fiel field</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>33</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2748511</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2748511'>GENERAL USER CUSTOM FIELDx</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2759799</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2759799'>~radio buttons</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2698330</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2698330'>Test Workflows</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2780613</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2780613'>A aaaa</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2780614</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2780614'>Radio button </label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2807224</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2807224'>sub dynamic textbox 1</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2807226</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2807226'>sub dyn select many 1</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2807227</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2807227'>sub dyn select radio</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2807108</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2807108'>Apples</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2807109</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2807109'>Oranges</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2807110</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2807110'>Pears</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>30</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858633</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858633'>Switch Org Variables </label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field><field><id>2858794</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858794'>Place</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858792</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858792'>BritishColumbia</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858793</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858793'>Ontario</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858797</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858797'>Municipal</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858798</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858798'>MunicipalTwo</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858857</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858857'>Parent Combo</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858858</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2858858'>Child A</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858859</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2858859'>Child B</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858860</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858860'>Parent Checkbox</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858861</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2858861'>Child Checkbox A</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>20</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858862</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2858862'>Child Combo A1</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858863</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2858863'>Child Combo A2</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2858864</id><name><![CDATA[<!--dynfieldhidden--><label for='cf_2858864'>Child Combo B1</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>10</fieldtype><updatable>true</updatable></field><field><id>2866409</id><name><![CDATA[<label for='cf_2866409'>UserId</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109</fieldtype><updatable>false</updatable></field></fields></contact></ssdoc>]]></ns:return>
      </ns:getContactResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get the value -109 from this:

```
[CDATA[<label for='cf_2866410'>UserId</label>]]]]>><![CDATA[</name><value></value><fieldtype>109
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

respXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())
respXmlHolder.declareNamespace("ns1","http://uta.WS.abc.com")

CDATAXml = respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns1:getCompanyResponse[1]/ns1:return[1]/text()")
log.info CDATAXml
CDATAXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(CDATAXml)

myval = CDATAXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//label[@for='cf_2866410']/fieldtype")
log.info myval
```

I would like to go to for example id - 2748473 and extract its fieldtype

Comment: Your response is not valid,can you post the valid one?

Comment: i could not post the full response here so i had to cut it down. i posted it again.please let me know if that is okie now.

Comment: It is not expected from you that an exact xml you need have it here. At least a sample of xml with similar structure, possibly with dummy data so that some one could reproduce the issue and allows to answer. Then using that you may need to apply to your case. By the what you have updated is still not a valid one.

Comment: @rao, apologizes. I posted the full response now. it is valid response now.

Comment: I am not sure why the response is embedded nested `CDATA`. More over, it is not clear where is `CDATA` starting and ending. May be you first need to get improve the response i.e., well-formed data.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far! Perhaps start by reading the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html

Comment: @SiKing, I have edited my answer. Please see my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it with the following:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

respXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())
respXmlHolder.declareNamespace("ns1","http://uta.abc.com")

CDATAXml = respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns1:getCompanyResponse[1]/ns1:return[1]")
CDATAXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(CDATAXml)

myval = CDATAXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//*[id='2858830']/fieldtype")
log.info myval
```